# How to use lm.fit instead on lm

Tags: r, lm

I want to use lm.fit for speed, but second version gives NAs

```
 sum <-   summary(lm(y~x))
 slope <-  sum$coefficients[2]
```

or

```
 sum <-   lm.fit(as.matrix(x,ncol=1),y)
 slope <-  sum$coefficients[2]
```

EDIT 1

I now see that sum$coefficients only has 1 value. Why is that and what is it? The help doesn't explain this

Comment: You gave it a design matrix with only one column. One column -> one coefficient.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but the documentation for `lm.fit` warns "should usually not be used directly unless by experienced users", and you seem sufficiently confused about how design matrices work that I would recommend reading up on some linear model theory before attempting to use this function.

Comment: Hence my asking for help -Joran. I have the solution now - thanks to everybody

Answer (score 5):

It would be easier to help with a reproducible example.

However, my guess is that you are missing an intercept in the second case.  Try `lm.fit(cbind(1,x),y)` and see if that gives you the comparison that you are looking for.

Other differences could be due to the other preprocessing that `lm` does before calling `lm.fit`, but we don't know what that is without seeing `x`.  Things like removing missing values, expanding a factor into dummy variables could also result in differences.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I tried sum$coefficients[1] and that appears to give me something that looks like the slope. Hopefully it is!

Comment: @ManInMoon, you should be **very careful**.  I'm guessing that what you got from `sum$coefficients[1]` was the slope of a regression fitted through the origin, which probably isn't what you want. (This is implicit in Greg's answer.)

Comment: @BenBolker If I use Greg's suggestion. How do I find the slope? Would it be sum$coefficients[1 OR 2]?

Comment: @ManInMoon, the 1st coefficient will be the intercept and the 2nd will be the slope, just like with `lm`.